# Let's think of a creative name for our chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

The chatroom name is so bland. "Coffee." Look at all the creative names others have thought up:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel
- "The Water Cooler" for The Workplace
- "The Whiteboard" for Programmers
- "The Nineteenth Byte" for Code Golf
- etc...

Can we think of a better name for our chatroom?

Only one idea per answer, please. Vote up the ideas that you like!

<sup>Stolen from [Lifehacks meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25/88), which was in turn stolen from [PPCG meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/3808). But that's okay, because I wrote both of those posts too. :P</sup>

Comment: Was about to post the same thing (almost)

Comment: Can't we all list our ideas in a community wiki answer, and we can choose our favorites in the comment section?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Percolator

Comment: Gotta love the way percolator just rolls off the tongue.

Comment: Its Time for the Percolator: ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVTvzqIHiNk

Comment: I also liked Percolator because it plays nicely on the idea of the best questions/answers rising to the top

Comment: based on this discussion would it need to be "The Moka Pot" instead? http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/60/tag-synonym-request

Comment: Plus a million for the Percolator!

Answer (score 9):

**The Grinder**

We are all delicious coffee beans ;-)

Comment: This sounds a bit too similar to a certain app to me.

Comment: @TomMedley `Java Load Testing Framework`? If thats the case i have never heard of it, and i'm a Java developer ;-)

Comment: "What are you doing on the computer dear?" "Just chatting on the Grinder, I'll be done in a minute!" "You *what?*"

Comment: Haha. I wasn't aware of Grindr, before now! lol :-)

Answer (score 6):

**The Coffehouse**

Since a coffeehouse is where you take a break and have a chat. So my vote goes for "[The Coffehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffeehouse)".

[image: "Discussing the War in a Paris Café", The Illustrated London News 17 September 1870]

<sup>"Discussing the War in a Paris Café", The Illustrated London News 17 September 1870</sup>

Answer (score 4):

'The coffee-mill' - grinding ourselves a coffee here

Answer (score 3):

"The roast"

followed by more text to sate the character demon.

Answer (score 3):

"Nighthawks".

Too subtle?
It is referring to the name of this quite famous painting of a café late at night:

[image]

(From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nighthawks))

Comment: This one is hands down my favorite :)

Answer (score 2):

just "café" ...

---

Above the line is my answer. The rest is just filler to fulfill minimum length criterion.

Answer (score 1):

"The Coffee Break"

Not exactly a thing as much as a time, but take it for what it's worth...

Answer (score 0):

## Moka Mocha

They rhyme and it sounds awesome and rolls off the tongue.

Answer (score -2):

Since we're throwing out ideas how about "Crema"

Answer (score -2):

**Bean Me Up**

This appeals to my sci-fi nerdy background!

I do know that it is an existing [Coffee Shop](http://beanmeup.com.au/), but if there are no copyright issues, it would be awesome!

Answer (score -2):

## Java

Comment: This name may require regular disambiguation from: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Answer (score -3):

"The Brewing Station"

Another idea that might work...

Answer (score -3):

### The Jampot

After the [first coffee shop in London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaica_Wine_House).

Answer (score -3):

"The Puck"

Was also thinking "The Whack Box", but terminology might not be consistent there. I think 'puck' is universal for the spent grounds in a portafilter.

Answer (score -3):

"Coffee Drops"

---

Or a variation on the idea, such as "Coffee Dripping", "Coffee Brewing".

Answer (score -4):

"The Baristas", or even "The Barista Room"

Answer (score -5):

"Stackbucks Coffee"

Sorry, that was too tempting... I like the chatty aspect, though.

Comment: I don't like the inclusion of an existing brand name in the branding of this stack exchange.